# modify specific row in filter separately pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to modify row in filter separately, what I think about is like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 6, 3, 6], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 8], 'c': [1, 5, 6, 8]})
mask = (df['a']==6)
df.loc[mask].loc[0,'c']=4
df.loc[mask].loc[1,'c']=5
```

When doing this I'll get the SettingWithCopyWarning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

But since I have use .loc already, I don't know how to solve this problem. Or is there anyway to do what I want?

thanks

**UPDATE**

original df looks like

```
   a  b  c
0  2  3  1
1  6  4  5
2  3  5  6
3  6  8  8
```

And after I done this

```
mask = (df['a']==6)
df.loc[mask].loc[0,'c']=4
df.loc[mask].loc[1,'c']=5
```

my desire output is

```
   a  b  c
0  2  3  1
1  6  4  4
2  3  5  6
3  6  8  5
```

Henry's code works , but I still want to know is there any way to modify the value one by one.

```
df.loc[(df['a'] == 6), 'c'] = [4, 5]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do: `df.loc[(df['a'] == 6), 'c'] = 4` ? Also as an aside you shouldn't mask the built-in `filter` function like that.

Comment: not exactly, i would want to modify it  separately, since `df.loc[df['a']==6]` will contain 2 rows. I will want to assign each row one by one.

Comment: Then `df.loc[(df['a'] == 6), 'c'] = [4, 5]`?

Comment: Can you post the dataframe output you'd like?

Comment: @HenryEcker the code works, thank you

Comment: @BLimitless I have update in the question